# Calling Oracle procedure from SQL Server stored procedure - getting error 'Must declare the scalar variable' when trying to send UDTT

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a Procedure called UpdateCase in an oracle database that I can not change. One of the parameters is an Object type. My goal is to call that stored procedure from MSSQL. We have created the linked server and a User Defined Table Type that mirrors the Object type in the oracle database. Here is the code to call the Procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spDMVUpdateCase]
    @CaseNumber INT = NULL,
    @User VARCHAR(50) = NULL
AS
DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT
DECLARE @ErrorState INT
DECLARE @CaseRec AS CRASH.CaseSubType
BEGIN
    EXECUTE('Call UpdateCase(?,?,?,?)',
             @CaseRec,
             @User,
             @ErrorState,
             @ErrorMessage) AT ALIS
END
```

When I try to execute this code I get 'Must declare the scalar variable "@CaseRec".'

Is there any way to send a non-scalar variable to an oracle procedure from MSSQL?

Comment: What type is your Oracle proc expecting for `CaseRec`?

Comment: CaseSubType is the type the proc is expecting,
Here is how they created the type 
'type CaseSubType is record {
     --Parameters--
}'
we are converting an oracle procedure to MSSQL to call it. Here is the original type, CaseRec Ais_Frm_Loccode_Alis.CaseSubType;

Comment: I can't imagine that table types are ever going to work, as they are not defined by ODBC. Oracle and SQL Server implement them differently

Comment: @Charlieface Is there any way to call the procedure from SQL when the oracle database has an Object Type as a parameter? The only other idea that I have is to make an oracle procedure for an oracle database I do have access to. Send that data to that one and create the object there. Then call UpdateCase from that procedure. But we are trying to avoid that.

Comment: Perhaps pass it as XML or JSON? I don't know what Oracle supports